# Matching a proper preposition with different words at once in a phrase

Tags: usage, phrases

> Sample sentence : To conquer the mountain, people need to be ambitious with the challenge and wisdom toward the mountain

I know "toward" can be used with "challenge" but
I hardly find "wisdom toward".

If I necessarily need to write this together with "and" like above
What could be the better option??

or any other suggestions ??

Comment: Your sample phrase doesn't really make any sense. Could you explain your question more thoroughly?

Comment: @CurtisWhite ah got it thanks, I have changed it. plz check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toward is not really used with wisdom. Challenge implies a direction of action, while wisdom does not since it is simply one's collected knowledge.

It may be more appropriate to say:

> To conquer the mountain, people need to be ambitious and wise in
>   challenging the mountain.

Comment: I like "To conquer the mountain, people need to be ambitious but use wisdom in challenging the mountain" better. The "but" seems to emphasize the limitations of using ambition alone better.

Comment: Yes, perhaps that makes more sense.